Unable to login to Azure Databricks Account Console
I have a personal Azure pay-as-you-go subscription in which I have the 'Global Administrator' role. I am also the databricks account administrator.
Until two weeks ago, I was able to access the databricks account console without any issues, but I am facing issues during the last 2 weeks as below. It's not only isolated to me. I have checked with other users in my user group and they are facing the same issue. All of them were able to access the account console in the past.
I am accessing the account console via the 'manage account' menu as below

This takes us to the page below with the error as shown here

It suggests the error is temporary, but I have been seeing it over the last 2 weeks.
As you can see below, the user I am trying to access has Global Administrator role.

Also, the workspace is a premium workspace as below

I have tried clearing the cache and also using a different browser. All of these return the same error.
As I could access the account console successfully in the past, I assume it's due to some recent changes to databricks. I have looked through the documentation to see if I need to add additional roles or privileges, but nothing is pointing to a solution.
Has anyone faced similar issue. If so, could you please help resolve this.
Please note that the Azure subscription is my personal pay-as-you-go subscription. Other people I spoke to also have the same issue with personal subscription, not corporate accounts.
Thanks.

I have pay as you go account and I'm able to login via manage account.

I see you tried clearing the cache or using another browser.  Can you please try incognito mode (without any plugins/extensions)

Hi @GaneshChandrasekaran - thanks for the comment. I just tried with a browser in incognito mode and unfortunately got the same error. I had this working a couple of weeks ago when other people had this issue. So, I assume this is a product update being rolled out incrementally (region at a time or something similar).

Also, I raised this in the databricks community here - https://community.databricks.com/t5/administration-architecture/unable-to-login-to-azure-databricks-account-console/td-p/82190. It appears this not only affects pay-as-you-go subscription. Another user on Visual Studio license has reported the same issue started last week.

It happens when you use generic emails (like Gmail, hotmail)
If you have a custom domain, add that to Azure Portal, make it Primary, and register that email. That solves the problem.
I cannot attach images here so will attach in the answer area.

Ramesh
Here is the solution from the Databricks Community page. I am copying the solution and linking it for future updates.

I have steps that should help many with this issue get connected
again. I hit this on my personal Azure pay-as-you-go account where I
now have to login as a different username to get to my Databricks
Account.
In Azure Portal, go to Azure Entra ID resource and see which users
exist. For me the admin user I normally log in with doesn't show
exactly, instead a similar username with #ext# in it shows up. If
there is an #ext# user that is similar to what you log in as, go to
portal.azure.com on a fresh browser session (such as incognito
browsing) and try logging in with that full username (should include
#ext#). You may need to reset password to get logged in as this user. After you get that working, go to Databricks Account login at
accounts.azuredatabricks.net and login with the #EXT# email. See
images below of how my typical username which I logged in with to
Databricks (training@dustinvannoy.com) is no longer showing up in
Microsoft Entra ID, but I now have the #ext# user
(training_dustinvannoy.com#EXT#@trainingdustinvannoy.onmicrosoft.com)
which has those important Azure admin permissions and I can use to
login to accounts.azuredatabricks.net.

https://community.databricks.com/t5/administration-architecture/unable-to-login-to-azure-databricks-account-console/m-p/83658/highlight/true#M1613

Thanks @Ganesh, Dustin Vannoy. This solution works. Microsoft also recommended a solution which requires us to create an external user with Global Administrator role. That also works. I am writing a document  with step by step instructions and I will share that here. Thanks

Based on the solution posted above by Ganesh and the solution given by Microsoft in their Q&A forum, I have written the step by step instructions with screenshots to workaround this issue. Please find the documentation with the instructions here - https://github.com/cloudboxacademy/azure_databricks_course/blob/main/known-issues/unable-to-login-to-azure-databricks-account-console.md
Hope it helps others! Thanks

As mentioned in the comment, I cannot add images there, so I'm adding them here.
Goto Azure portal, add your custom domain and email@domain as another admin user.


Thanks @Ganesh, I appreciate that using a custom domain can help resolve this. As I said, I do not see this issue in my corporate account as that uses custom domain. This is just an issue with the personal account and most of the people learning the product don't have a custom domain. So, I am looking for a solution for that. Do you think Microsoft/ Databricks have made changes to the product in relation to this so that we can't use generic accounts such as outlook.com, gmail etc which will be a shame. Or is this an untended product update recently as it was working a week ago? Thanks

Based on the solution posted above by Ganesh and the solution given by Microsoft in their Q&A forum, I have written the step by step instructions with screenshots to workaround this issue. Please find the documentation with the instructions here - https://github.com/cloudboxacademy/azure_databricks_course/blob/main/known-issues/unable-to-login-to-azure-databricks-account-console.md
Hope it helps others! Thanks
